# jquery onclick function not firing with rails link_to_remote

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, onclick, link-to-remote

In the js file of the page, inside `$(document).ready(function() {})` I have

```
$(".school a").live("click", function (e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  ....;
  jsFunc(param1, param2, param3);
});
```

Now the div with the class school has  tags generated by rails link_to_remote with `:url`, `:action`, `:before`, `:html`.

On clicking on this link it does all that it should do with regards to link_to_remote, but somehow the onclick event in the document.ready does not attach to it. Why would this be happening? The jsFunc all it does is post to a url async-ly, i figured out that stuffing that post url in the `:before` of the link_to_remote would work - but is there a more elegant way of just being able to use the attach functionality

Comment: `return false` is a whole lot better than just `preventDefault`. `preventDefault` fails on IE too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the link_to_remote helper depends on Prototype; if you've switched to jQuery, Rails's javascript helpers such as link_to_remote might not work.

Answer (score 0):

link_to_remote works with the onclick attribute. Apparently these get called before any bind/live events are processed, so your preventDefaults happens too late.

In my case I just want to prevent the 'second' click on the link, so I just nulled the "onclick" attribute during the first click:

```
/* not (yet) well tested */
function doubleClickhandler(event) {
  var t = $(event.target);

  if (t.data("clicked")) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    t.data("clicked", true);
    if (t.attr("onclick")) {
      /* forcefully remove onclick handler */
      t.attr("onclick", "");
    }
  }
}

function setupdoubleClickHandlers() {
  $("a.doubleclick").each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.removeClass("doubleclick"); /* prevent multiple setups */
    el.bind("click", doubleClickhandler);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setupdoubleClickHandlers();
  $(document).bind('reveal.facebox updatedfacebox', function() {
    setupdoubleClickHandlers();
  });
});
```